# Navigate to route sent on Push Notification Payload

Tags: ionic2

I have an ionic2 app receiving push notifications from ionic.io. On the notification payload I'm sending the desired route to be navigated to.

```
let route = notification.payload.route;

if (route) {
  that.navCtrl.push(route, notification.payload);
}
```

The problem is that the payload comes as a string, while the navCtrl is expecting to receive the route value. Like **myPage** from this import:

```
import { myPage } from '../pages.ts';
```

What is the best way to convert the string? or if there is a better way to do this, feel free to mention that as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the navigation options are limited you could use a switch to send the user to the page, like:

```
let route = notification.payload.route;

if (route) {
  switch(route){
    case 'home':
      that.navCtrl.push(MyHomePage, notification.payload);
      break;

    case 'Users':
      that.navCtrl.push(MyUsersPage, notification.payload);
      break;

    case ...
  }
}
```

It's not the most beautiful way, but should work.

### EDIT - IONIC 3 LAZY LOADING WAY

So since you want to just use a string containing the page selector i think the only way able for you to do this is using lazy loading components.

Before you start, if your project is not on Ionic 3, follow this [Changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) steps to upgrade it.

1) You need to delete the pages you want to lazyload from your `app.module.ts` `entryComponents` and `declatarions`, also, of course, delete the page imports. 
So from this

```
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp, HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp, HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
```

It'll looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
```

2) On every lazy loaded folder you have 3 files, like

```
-home
|- home.html
|- home.scss
|- home.ts
```

And you need to create another file, a `home.module.ts`

3) On your `home.module.ts` you'll need this code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HomePage } from './home';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [HomePage],
    imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage)],
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

4) On your `home.ts` you'll need to import `IonicPage` decorator and use it above your `@Component` decorator

```
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
```

5) Now you're ready to use lazy loading, you don't need to import the page and then use it when pushing/poping pages anymore, you need to pass it as a string.
So if you used `this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, data);` now you can use `this.navCtrl.push('HomePage', data);` and let the deep linking take care of that for you.

If you neeed more information, see this [lazy loading doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGokwMXPQItZmTHZQbTO4qwj_SQymFhRS_nJmiH0K3w/edit) about how to implement this feature, but as far as i see this is the only way you can use routing with passing a string value.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Gabriel. That would work, but I'm trying to avoid hard coding the value myself. I would like the notification to control that dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for that @GabrielWabiz, I believe this accomplishes what I need but it would be too much for now, I'll go with your initial suggestion to use a switch. Thank you.

Comment: @GabrielBarreto, This is not working when I click on the notification and open the app.