# Local Notifications in Mobile Application

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

to give you an overview of what i'm doing, i have a ionic mobile application that uses firebase as its database . One of its features that im implementing is local notifications. Here are my codes

HTML CODE

```
   <button ion-button full (click)="scheduleNotification()">schedule</button>
   <button ion-button full (click)="scheduleNotification2()">schedule</button>
```

so this is the html code where in there a button allowing you to click or schedule a notification

TYPESCRIPT CODE

```
      import { Component } from '@angular/core';
      import { NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
      import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
    @Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
     templateUrl: 'home.html'
   })
    export class HomePage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private 
    localNotif:LocalNotifications, private platform:Platform) {

     }

    scheduleNotification() {
     this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
      this.localNotif.schedule({
    
        title:'Attention',
        text:'Rk notification',
        at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 5000),
       
      });
      });
    }
     
     scheduleNotification2() {
     this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
      this.localNotif.schedule({
    
        title:'Attention',
        text:'Rk notification',
        at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 5000),
       
      });
      });
    }


  
}
```

so the problem here is that, when i click both buttons for the notification to pop out , it only overrides the other. so it only displays one notification. i wanted to display both without overiding. how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an `id` to your `localNotification`, it must be a number and [by default it's 0](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling), so if you don't declare an id it'll override the previous scheduled notification.

If the user is able to manipulate the notifications (like editing, deleting, updating) i recommend saving this id somewhere so the user can be able of doing so.

Since the id needs to be unique there's a lot of ways of generating ids, since i don't know how often your user is going to create notifications i'll use the most simple way of generating that's `Math.random()`.

```
scheduleNotification() {
 this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
  this.localNotif.schedule({
    id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000)), // this'll generate an id of 7 random digits
    title:'Attention',
    text:'Rk notification',
    at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 5000),
  });
  });
}
```

Another advice i can give is manipulating time for the manipulations in the smallest time unit possible, always try using milliseconds or seconds.

Hope this help.

Comment: heyyy gabriel. it works perfectly fine thank you very much. can i ask another question? is it possible when there's a notification and when you click that notification it goes to a certain page? like theres a message notification and when clicked, it goes to the message page?

Comment: @Jennica i'm glad i helped. Yes it is possible, there's a couple of answers including mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359716/navigate-to-route-sent-on-push-notification-payload/43371831#43371831 
You can lazy load your applications and send the page you want to open in your notification payload, then you'l have a method only for opening/ on tap of your notification, inside that method you'll redirect the user

Comment: hi gabriel barreto. I read and analyzed the link you have given but im having a hard as to how to do it. can you give me an example? thankss

Comment: I'm sorry Jennica this is the example i can give, it's literally a code i've writen. Try to find a solution and code it for yourself, if you can't achieve something just ask a new question with your code and i'll try to help.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a alert conrtroller
inreplace of localnotification
 visit https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: i don't know unother way

Comment: This is not what op wants, she/he clearly needs a localNotification, using alert doesn't works for this.